# How to add CPS link info to Legal Notice tab?

Tags: itext7

How to add CPS link info to Legal Notice tab in certificate viewer of a Pdf?

I want when "Show Issuer Policy" button clicked it will redirected to CPS url.

I need help

thank you.

[image]

Comment: Show us some code that represents the button. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26242991).

Comment: Hi.. the button is from Certificate Viewer, you can see that button if you click "Certificate Details" then go to Legal Notice tab

Comment: I'm not sure but you may want to try using *certificate policies extensions* in the signer and/or issuer certificate, cf. [RFC 5280 section 4.2.1.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.4).

Comment: Can I do this with itext7?